# vanilla JS AJAX call function in PHP ? WP_query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, fetch

Im having trouble trying to call my function in my Function.php this is the function

1. enqueue script & localize

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc_shop', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wc_shop.js', array('') );

    wp_localize_script( 'wc_shop', 'a_product_filter',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

2. the Function thats in function.php that im trying to call that filters product

```
add_action('wp_ajax_a_product_filter', 'a_product_filter');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_a_product_filter', 'a_product_filter');
function a_product_filter() {
  echo "called";
  $args = array( 
              'post_type'    => 'product', 
              'posts_per_page' => 5, 
              'product_tag'    => 'FEMALE' //just for testing without passing a variable
              );
        
        // Create the new query
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        // Get products number
        $product_count = $loop->post_count;
        
        // If results
        if( $product_count > 0 ) :
        
          echo '<ul class="products">';
          
            // Start the loop
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); //global $product;
            
              //global $post;
              wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

              echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'.get_the_title($product_id).'</a>';
              
              if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
                echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
              else 
                echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce .'/assets/images/placeholder.png" alt="" width="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_catalog_image_width').'px" height="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_catalog_image_height').'px" />';
          
            endwhile;
          
          echo '</ul><!--/.products-->';
        
        else :
        
          _e('No product matching your criteria.');
        
        endif; // endif $product_count > 0
}
```

3. this is the call I'm calling from the front end i cant even get the a_product_filter to echo 'called'

```
function ajax_call_test(){
  // data to be sent to the POST request
  let _data = {
    action : 'a_product_filter',
    
  }

  fetch(a_product_filter.ajax_url , {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(_data),
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
  })
  .then(response => response.json()) 
  .then(json => console.log(json));
  
}
```

I keep getting  400 Bad Request can someone help me and tell me what is wrong with this

Comment: For a start your php is returning HTML so you want `response.text()` **not** `response.json()`. Check your php call returning what you expect by either calling as a GET through your browser or POST by using a tool such as Postman.

Comment: im not sure why you're sending a json header to the backend, shouldn't that be just a normal post form urlencoded?

Answer (score 1):

Just like what I have stated in the comments, the backend requires you to send a request in normal POST fashion, not in JSON.

So use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as your header and send query string in the body, not JSON.

```
let _data = { action : 'a_product_filter', product_something: 'value that i want to send to the server'};
fetch(a_product_filter.ajax_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: (new URLSearchParams(_data)).toString(),
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(product_html => document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML(product_html));
// put the markup created by server and put it inside somewhere in the frontend
```

Then on the backend, prepare for that request. Here's an *untested* code that you can use in the server. So that when the front end requests it, your server (the PHP code that will handle the request will give out the markup with the product you want to respond).

Just follow this idea. Create the markup and respond (`echo` and `exit`).

```
add_action('wp_ajax_a_product_filter', 'a_product_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_a_product_filter', 'a_product_filter');
function a_product_filter() {
    // $variable = $_POST['product_something'];
    $html_markup = _e('No product matching your criteria.');
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'product_tag' => 'FEMALE' //just for testing without passing a variable
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($loop->found_posts > 0) {
        // get template in string
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $html_markup = '<ul class="products">';
        foreach ($loop->get_posts() as $post) {
            $html_markup .= '<li>'; // initialize list item    
            $html_markup .= $template; // add the template
            $html_markup .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_title($post->ID). '</a>'; // link and title
            $html_markup .= has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); : '<img src="placeholder.jpg" />' ; // image of product
            $html_markup .= '</li>'; // end list item
        }
        $html_markup .= '</ul>';
    }

    echo $html_markup;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: sidenote: use an ajax nonce as additional checking

Comment: thxx i fixed it by wrapping the body in ```new URLSearchParams()``` and headers to ```headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}``` as you mentioned in your answer and solved it

originally my Jquery ajax call was working and figured the body was different in the request just didn't know how to change Fetchs body to an Object

would of upvote you but i cant cause new account restriction

Comment: @Ojisan sure no prob glad this helped